# How do I create x amount of lists/sets that i can later add together?

Tags: python, list, loops, random, set

I'm doing a project where i have to check if something is in another set and if it is then i have to combine the sets.

My question is how do i create x amount of sets with y amount of values in it.

i want to randomize this kind of data
there are x sets of sets with between y1 and y2 "names"
Example:

```
    x=5
    y1=2
    y2=4
    ["1","2","3"]
    ["6","1","2"]
    ["9","7","4","0"]
    ["6","8","1"]
    ["1","5"]
```

There are 5 sets of sets with between 2 and 4 "names"

Then i need to be able to put the two sets together if one value is in multiple sets, in this case it would look something like this when done:

```
    ["1","2","3","6","8","5"]
    ["9","7","4","0"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you come up with some code? Where are you stuck now with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code doing roughly what you want. Look up the documentation on [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and [random numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) for a more thorough understanding of what's going on here.

```
import random

# make a single set of random numbers in [0, 10), with number of elements in [y1, y2]
random_set = set(random.sample(range(10), random.randint(y1, y2)))

# make x sets of them
random_sets = [set(random.sample(range(10), random.randint(y1, y2))) for _ in range(x)]

# merge sets containing a given element
def merge_sets(list_of_sets, elem):
    # create an empty set
    elem_set = set()
    for s in list_of_sets:
        # go through all the sets in the list, and if those sets contain the 
        # element we're looking for, merge them into the new set
        if elem in s:
            elem_set |= s
    # return the list of new set plus those sets that didn't contain our element
    return [elem_set] + [s for s in list_of_sets if elem not in s]
```